# Generate slug with german umlauts

Tags: php, regex

I try to generate a slug from a string, but I got some problems with the german umlauts:

```
$text = 'Ein schöner Text';
$text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);
$text = trim($text, '-');
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
$text = strtolower($text);
$text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
```

The result should be: 'ein-schoener-text'

Answer (score -1):

Change the second preg_replace line to the below because to match any letter in any language you need to use `\p{L}`  pattern.

```
$text = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\d]+~u', '-', $text);
```

Code:

```
<?php
$text = 'Ein schöner Text';
$text = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\d]+~u', '-', $text);
$text = trim($text, '-');
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
$text = strtolower($text);
$text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Output:

```
ein-schoner-text
```

Comment: I got the output 'ein-schner-text'.

Comment: but i got the above output. `ö` is translated to `o`

Comment: I don't get the `o`. By the way: It should be `oe` :-)